# Solving wave PDE

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the wave PDE with NDSolve. Below is the equation:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[0, t] == 0, 
u[10, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 5, D[u[x, 0] == 0]}, 
u[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

When I try to get the solution I get the following error:

> NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
>
> NDSolve::ndinpd: The initial conditions did not evaluate to an array of numbers of depth 1 on the spatial grid. Initial conditions for partial differential equations should be specified as scalar functions of the spatial variables.

My Boundary conditions are:

- when x=0 (at t=0) is zero
- when x=10 (at t=0) is also zero

My Initial conditions are:

- u when $t=0$ g[x]=5
- derivative of u when t=0 is zero

By this initial condition it means the string is stretched in vertical direction by 5 units at its center, initial velocity being zero and then let go.

I want to check the wave pattern of the string with these conditions.

Comment: Notice that your last equation corresponding to "derivative of u when t=0 is zero" doesn't seem to be syntactically correct: `D[u[x, 0] == 0]`. This does not conform to the syntax of the `D` function, as you yourself have used it elsewhere. You should probably start by correcting that.

Comment: I get it now. I need to add t in that derivative, which would mean derivative w.r.t time, which would complete the D function. Thanks MarcoB for pointing this out.

Comment: u[0,0] == 5 == 0?

Comment: No such term in the equation

Comment: @tsuresuregusa I don't understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @MarcoB `u[0, t] == 0, 
u[10, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 5` the conditions are ill-defined for u[0,0], approaching from one side is 5 but from the other is 0.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa OK I see what you mean now. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: String fixed at both ends. U is 0 at x=0 and U is 0 at x=10, which is the other end of the string. String is stretched 5 units vertically, halfway of the string, held there and left. Need to calculate wave pattern.

Comment: halfway of the string is in x==5, not in x==0.

Comment: Could you help me with the correct boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: I think you would spend your time more wisely if go again to a book and read how to solve the wave equation in 1D. This problem is analytical so can be solved easily by normal modes. Furthermore, your initial condition is unphysical, it implies the string is discontinuous which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7):

There are two different methods for solving the OP"s problem :

- The *Method of Lines* with the option `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid"...`
- The *Method of Lines* with the option `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}`. This solution is the Mathematica 10 implementation of the *Finite Element Method* for transcient PDEs.

In both cases the *Method of Lines* does the temporal integration.

Apart from this, the solution will be given for the following cases :

**1) OP's equation and initial condition u[x,0] == triangle : `u[x,0] == 5 - Abs[x-5]` :**

[image]

**2) Because the exact OP's equation doesn't give a realistic result, the equation is modified by adding some loss and the result is shown**

**3) initial condition : `u[x,0] == 5` :**

[image]

**1) initial condition u[x,0] == triangle, Lossless**

Method of Lines with TensorProductGrid

```
solTensorLossless = 
  NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[0, t] == 0, 
     u[10, t] == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == 5 - Abs[x - 5], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 15}, 


 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> {50}, "MaxPoints" -> {100}, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}][[1, 1, 2]];

Table[Labeled[
    Plot[solTensorLossless[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}], t], {t, 0, 15, 0.2}]  // 
  Export["TensorLossLess.gif", #] &;

SystemOpen["TensorLossLess.gif"]
```

[image]

Method of Lines with Finite Elements

```
solFEMLossless = 
  NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[0, t] == 0, 
     u[10, t] == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == 5 - Abs[x - 5], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 15}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}][[1, 1, 2]];

Table[Labeled[
    Plot[solFEMLossless[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}], t], {t, 0, 15, 0.2}]  // 
  Export["FEMLossLess.gif", #] &;

SystemOpen["FEMLossLess.gif"]
```

[image]

**2) initial condition u[x,0] == triangle, Lossy**

Method of Lines with TensorProductGrid

```
solTensorLossy = 
  NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + 0.3 D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == 
      2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[0, t] == 0, u[10, t] == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == 5 - Abs[x - 5], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 15}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> {50}, "MaxPoints" -> {100}, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}][[1, 1, 2]];

Table[Labeled[
    Plot[solTensorLossy[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}], t], {t, 0, 15, 0.2}]  // 
  Export["TensorLossy.gif", #] &;

SystemOpen["TensorLossy.gif"]
```

[image]

Method of Lines with Finite Elements

```
solFEMLossy = 
  NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + 0.3 D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == 
      2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], u[0, t] == 0, u[10, t] == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == 5 - Abs[x - 5], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 15}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}][[1, 1, 2]];

Table[Labeled[
    Plot[solFEMLossy[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}], t], {t, 0, 15, 0.2}]  // 
  Export["FEMLossy.gif", #] &;

SystemOpen["FEMLossy.gif"]
```

[image]

**3) initial condition : `u[x,0] == 5`**

Method of Lines + TensorProductGrid

```
solTensorProductGrid00 = 
  NDSolve[{
          D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
          u[0, t] == 0, 
          u[10, t] == 0,
          u[x, 0] == 5,
          (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0
         }, 
         u,
         {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, 
         Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
                    "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
                    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
                                                "MinPoints" -> {50},
                                                "MaxPoints" -> {100},
                                                "DifferenceOrder" ->"Pseudospectral" 
                                               }
                   }
        ];

solTensorProductGrid = solTensorProductGrid00[[1, 1, 2]];

Plot3D[solTensorProductGrid[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

**Method of Lines + Finite Element**

```
solFiniteElementMethod00 = 
 NDSolve[{
         D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 2*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}],
         u[0, t] == 0, 
         u[10, t] == 0,
         u[x, 0] == 5,
         (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0
         }, 
         u,
         {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, 
         Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
                    "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
                    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}
        ]

solFiniteElementMethod = solFiniteElementMethod00[[1, 1, 2]];

Plot3D[solFiniteElementMethod[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Note : the theorical solution is : two perfect steps propagating from the edges towrad center (hyperbolic PDEs propagate discontinuities). Here the steps are not perfect since we dont have u[0,t]=u[10,t]=0

My version of Mathematica : 10.0.2.0 Windows 64 bits

Comment: If you replace the "TensorProductGrid" with "FinteElement" and remove "MaxPionts" you'll get FEM

Comment: Andre, in MMA 10.4.0 on Win7-64 your code seems to throw some errors and refuses to execute ([output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UTj0C.png)). What version are you using?

Comment: in my machine keeps on running forever, even after fixing the boundary conditions.

Comment: I think the question was unclear about the initial condition. It's probably supposed to be `u[x,0] == 5 - Abs[x-5]` to get a triangle shape. I would have voted to close it if you hadn't already put in the work... Maybe you could try it for this more physical initial condition instead.