# how to fix this PDE numerical solution (NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following code:

```
ClearAll[x, t, u];
a = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, 
   u[0, t] == t}, u, {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
Plot3D[{u[x, t] /. sol}, {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

This results in the following graph :

[image]

As you can see, the graph is not smooth as it should be. I've tried to fix it by adding `MaxStepSize -> 0.01`.  This changes the graph somewhat, but doesn't really fix it as you can see.

**How do I get a smooth graph? what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to point out the problem doesn't have a *classical* solution, which should be $C^1$ continuous and satisfy all the i.c. and b.c. in the whole interested domain. This can be easily proven by finding the general solution of the equation:

```
{eq, ic, bc} = {D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, u[0, t] == t}
generalsol = First@DSolve[eq, u, {x, t}]
(* {u -> Function[{x, t}, C[1][t + x]]} *)
```

and substituting it to i.c. and b.c.:

```
{ic, bc} /. generalsol
(* {C[1][x] == x^2, C[1][t] == t} *)
```

Clearly the only function relationship satisfying `ic` is `Function[a, a^2]`, while the one satisfying `bc` is `Function[a, a]`, so they can't be satisfied simultaneously, as long as we require the solution to be smooth.

Still, if we lower our requirement a bit i.e. allow solution that doesn't satisfy the equation and corresponding i.c. and b.c. in some *region*, we can find 
 *weak* solution. (Well, to be honest I'm not sure if it's the correct terminology. I've asked it [in Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2271260/58219).)

One weak solution can be found by using Laplace transform on `t` (I'll use [`pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84297/1871) for the task):

```
(* Definition of pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the post above. *)
asol[x_, t_] = pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform[{eq, bc}, ic, u[x, t], t, x]
(* (t + x)^2 + (t - t^2 + x - 2 t x - x^2) HeavisideTheta[t + x] *)
```

It's the same as given by `DSolve`, as shown in [zhk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8538/zhk)'s answer.

Notice this solution does not satisfy the original equation at $t+x=0$ (`HeavisideTheta` isn't defined at `0`), `ic` when $x>0$ and `bc` when $t<0$:

```
Plot[Subtract @@ ic /. u -> asol // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This isn't the only possible weak solution, if we treat `x` as time i.e.:

```
asol2[x_, t_] = pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform[{eq, ic}, bc, u[x, t], x, t]
(* t + x - (t + x) HeavisideTheta[t + x] + (t + x)^2 HeavisideTheta[t + x] *)
```

This solution does not satisfy the original equation at $t+x=0$, `ic` when $x<0$ and `bc` when $t>0$.

As you see, when weak solution comes on stage, the problem doesn't have a unique solution. If neither of the 2 solutions above is the one you need, there must be a missing **auxiliary conditions**. As to auxiliary condition, here's an example:

[Position of discontinuous coefficient influences the solution of PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871)

Finally, I believe the reason why `NDSolve` has trouble in finding the numeric solution of the problem is, currently `NDSolve` doesn't have a strong enough support for weak solution problem. Here's just another few troublesome cases:

[1D Euler equations (fluid dynamics) with NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11748/1871)

[Circumvent NDSolve::bdord: error for 1-D Euler Equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24417/1871)

[Solving wave equation with singular initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144100/1871)

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what was missing from my answer, would you please elaborate? I'm not trying to complain here, I'm just curious about what I can do to improve my answer.

Comment: Your statement about a weak solution is unbased. Up to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution , a weak solution must satisfy the condition after " then an integrable function u would be said to be a weak solution if" in the cited Wiki article. This condition is not verified by you. Also there are problems with IC. @xzczd:

Comment: @user64494 Then I think LaplaceTransform, which is essentially a integration, plays exactly the role of that "condition". As to the i.c., the definition in the wiki page doesn't have any requirement for it, and I think the "problem" with i.c. does not contradict the definition: if the weak solution may not satisfy the equation in some "region", then why can't it be on the boundary?

Comment: I prefer solid arguments supplied with codes and references over unbased words. @xzczd

Comment: @user64494 I've rephrased my answer to make it more prudent.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use *DSolve* if it is solving the PDE?

```
ClearAll[x, t, u];
a = 10;
sol = DSolve[{D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, u[0, t] == t}, u, {x, -a, a},
             {t, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[{u[x, t] /. sol}, {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: The exact solution does not seem to be true. Look at the output of FullSimplify[{D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, 
   u[0, t] == t} /. %, Assumptions -> t > 0] @zhk

Comment: See the executed code in pdf file through https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyag64abroxmdvo/Bug%20in%20DSolve.pdf?dl=0 and in nb file through https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sjhkkizstlqq27/Bug%20in%20DSolve.nb?dl=0 @zhk

Comment: But :`sol = DSolve[{D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, 
   u[0, t] == t}, 
  u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 
   10}]; FullSimplify[{D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2,
    u[0, t] == t} /. sol, Assumptions -> {t > 0, x < 0}]` is `{{True, True, True}}`