# Forcing at least $n$ spatial steps in solving a 1D spatio-temporal PDE problem with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to solve the telegraph equation with a spatial discretization forced at 200 points. I tried:

```
reg = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
shape = Cos[16 π (x - 0.5)] D[0.125 Erf[(x - 0.5)/0.125], x];
op = D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - D[u[t, x], {t, 2}];
ics = {u[0, x] == shape, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ics}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x} ∈ reg, MaxStepSize -> 0.005];
Plot[shape, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,Frame -> True]
Plot[sol[0, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1.5}, Frame -> True]
```

The plots show that `NDSolve` has chosen 20 spatial points. My `MaxStepSize` option is used for the temporal variable `t` and not for the spatial variable `x`.

1. What is the `NDSolve` option or syntax for forcing 200 spatial points?
2. Where is this information in the `NDSolve` documentation?
3. Is there a `NDSolve` method that would have by default discretize more cleverly?

Edited question given the first answers that were posted:

5. How to force the initial spatial meshing at 200 points, keeping the region specification for x and consequently the finiteElement method ?

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113367/5467)

Comment: replacing `NDSolve` by `NDSolveValue` wouldn't help at all.

Comment: Strange: I had not asked question 4 in my post...

Answer (score 4):

```
shape = Cos[16 \[Pi] (x - 0.5)] D[0.125 Erf[(x - 0.5)/0.125], x];
op = D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - D[u[t, x], {t, 2}];
ics = {u[0, x] == shape, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
bc = {u[t, 0] == shape /. x -> 0, u[t, 1] == shape /. x -> 1};
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ics, bc}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 213, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
{Plot[shape, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True],
 Plot[sol[0, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1.5}, Frame -> True]}

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Good. Thank you, but your NDSolve syntax makes me loose several things: 1) the method option is incompatible my x specification in a region: x \element reg. 2) So I loose the perfectly reflective boundary condition corresponding to the default zero neumann values when no boundary conditions are specified. 3) I loose the clever time integration with adaptive  timesteps. I tried to keep my syntax and just add your method option I but get an error...

Comment: @user3650925 I added boundary conditions compatible with the initial data. If you want other boundary conditions, then just use them (change `bc`).

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out several issues.

> The plots show that NDSolve has chosen **20** spatial points.

Well, I don't know why you think the plots show the number of grid points is `20`, but you're wrong. The number of mesh coordinates (yeah the `FiniteElement` Method has been chosen for spatial discretization because of the `{x} ∈ reg`, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/1871) for more information ) can be checked by

```
coord = Flatten@sol["Coordinates"][[2]]["Coordinates"] // Sort
(* {0., 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.225, 0.25, 0.275, 0.3, 
0.325, 0.35, 0.375, 0.4, 0.425, 0.45, 0.475, 0.5, 0.525, 0.55, 0.575, 0.6, 0.625, 0.65, 
0.675, 0.7, 0.725, 0.75, 0.775, 0.8, 0.825, 0.85, 0.875, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 0.975, 1.} *)

coord // Length
(* 41 *)
```

The next important issue is boundary condition (b.c.). I'm not sure why you don't add b.c. to the system, but you're wrong again if you think `NDSolveValue` will be forced to solve an initial value problem (IVP) i.e. a problem defined in $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$. The b.c. at $x=0$ and $x= 1$ is Neumann 0 condition i.e. `NeumannValue[0,…]` in this case, for more information check the **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue`. If you need to approximate infinity, consider starting from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128516/1871).

Finally I'd like to add, it's possible to use `MaxStepSize` to control grid size in $x$ direction if `TensorProductGrid` method is used for spatial discretization. We just need to use a `List` as the option value, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189770/1871) is an example. Nevertheless, I don't recommend using this method to control spatial grid, because there's no `MinStepSize` for `NDSolve`. (The `MinStepSize` option mentioned in e.g. `NDSolveValue::mxsst` warning is an option for `TensorProductGrid` method. )

Comment: Thank you.Sorry for the sentence "The plots show that NDSolve has chosen 20 spatial points." I should have said "The plots show that NDSolve has chosen an insufficient number of spatial points." Concerning the bc, I want the default bc taken by NDSolve when you specifiy the saptial coordiantes by a region, i.e. 0 Neumann values. In other worfd, the bc are hidden, but are well defined and correspond to what I want. I now study your links. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The answer I was looking for is the following:
Add a Method option in NDSolve that is compatible with the method that NDSolve chooses by itself given your PDEs syntax. Then add your discretization specification in the sub-options. Here, the solution is:

```
NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ics}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x} \[Element] reg, 
Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.005}}]
```

With and without the Method option the final result is either correct (regeneration of the shape at time t=2, after two reflections on the region boundaries), or completely False:

[image: Correct with the Method option specifying the MaxCellMeasure sub-sub-option]

[image: Incorrect with default NDSolve parameters]

Now, there is a correlative question: In the solution above I specify the stepsize manually to get sufficient meshing and a correct solution. A much better solution would be to force NDSolve to check the validity of its solution and refine the spatial stepsize by itself... I create a separate post for this question.

Comment: I think this is the correct way to go.